# Which verb form should I use in the sentence "What we really do is supply/supplying our customers with top-notch services"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, verb-forms

To me, 'supplying' sounds more natural. Yet, a friend of mine from the UK says it should go without -ing. Please advise, which verb form is more preferable.

Comment: Both "supply" and "supplying" should be OK in your example.  In the variant, "Our goal is supplying our customers with...", you cannot just say "supply", but you could say "to supply"

Comment: If you used *supplying*, you would need to rephrase the sentence in order to accommodate it grammatically. In other words, while either word is fine, only *supply* is grammatical in the *existing* version of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies. So, as I can understand, if I want to use _supplying_, I should make it like "What we are really doing is supplying <...>," right?

Comment: If this is intended as a statement of your business model, then the choice is clear. It needs to be _supply_, not _supplying:_ _What we do is (to) supply our customers ..._ (You should definitely omit the _really_ in this context). The resulting sentence construction is usually called a _pseudo-cleft_. More here: http://www.grammaring.com/pseudo-cleft-sentences

Answer (score -1):

"[**Really**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/really)" is a weak adverb in this sentence and should be deleted. The sentence should read, "What we do is supply our customers with top-notch services," or more simply, "We supply our customers with top-notch services." "What we do" isn't *really* needed.